# PHP error log - not showing source

Tags: php, iis, error-log

I have a frequently recurring error in my PHP error log file, but I have no idea of the origin. Is there a way to get more information about it? I would like to at least find the site (out of 100 or so) that it relates to.

```
[05-Apr-2018 14:03:22 UTC] script not found:<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have access to the `httpd.conf` file so you can check the `LogFormat`

Comment: Well, it's IIS on Windows so there's no httpd.conf file, but I do have access to the ApplicationHost.config file. I don't see an error format related setting in there though. All other errors are logged with a much fuller set of information, eg: [05-Apr-2018 20:54:59 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'cid' in [path-to-file]\front-end.php on line 76 so I think the format is ok. It's pretty much just this one error that is so basic.